# Statement that produces list with "int" structure?

Tags: r, list, int, lda

I am familiarizing myself with Jonathan Chang and co-authors' `lda` R package to prepare doing similar analysis of my own. I checked out the structure of the built-in `cora.documents` and `cora.cites` data, they are stored in list format, but like this

```html
library(lda)
str(cora.cites)
List of 2410
 $ : int [1:2] 484 389
 $ : int(0) 
 $ : int(0) 
 $ : int [1:3] 177 416 533
 $ : int 153
 $ : int(0) 
 $ : int(0) 
 $ : int(0) 
 $ : int(0) 
 $ : int(0) 
 $ : int(0) 
 $ : int 139
 $ : int 433
 $ : int [1:16] 233 391 350 208 484 666 218 630 28 656 ...
 $ : int [1:8] 210 624 229 136 356 228 289 73
 $ : int(0)
```

where

```html
class(cora.cites)
[1] "list"
class(cora.cites[1])
[1] "list"
```

But if I were to build a data of similar structure, for example,

```html
list1 <- list(484, 389)
list2 <- list(0)
list3 <- list(0)
list4 <- list(177, 416, 533)
my_list <- list(list1, list2, list3, list4)
```

It turned out as

```html
str(my_list)
List of 4
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ : num 484
  ..$ : num 389
 $ :List of 1
  ..$ : num 0
 $ :List of 1
  ..$ : num 0
 $ :List of 3
  ..$ : num 177
  ..$ : num 416
  ..$ : num 533
```

which does not come with the `int` and dimension `[,]` information listed as the `cora.cites` data.

How can I generate a data of list format with structure like the `lda` package's sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along the lines of:

```
x<-list(integer(5),integer(5))
str(x)
# List of 2
# $ : int [1:5] 0 0 0 0 0
# $ : int [1:5] 0 0 0 0 0
```

If you observe what you did, you created `lists` and enclosed them within a `list`. Hence, you obtained lists as elements of `my_list`. But if you check `cora.sites` structure, the elements are `vectors` of `integer` type. Hence, you should pass integer vectors in the `list` function.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried applying `as.integer()` to my numeric values, it did turn out the $ : int [,] structure, but I did not notice elements of `vector` type (thanks for raising this!).